# Treeview drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm using the jQuery droppable/dragable to reorder a treeview (made up of ul/li items)

I have no problems making a  element and dragging it into the tree

When I define the

items to be draggable, the code doesn´t work any more (the items are classed as "droppables" but the drop event won´t run)

Isn't this supposed to be possible?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to answer this question without your code and (if possible) a link to your development page.

However if you want a tree view you should be using sortable instead of draggable/droppable.

[Link removed because I can only paste one link!]

OR, best of all, use a Tree plugin.  This page links to the better ones.

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138128/Tree